# chef: cant use depends 'httpd' in metadata.rb

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I cannot get my chef cookbook to use `depends 'httpd'`, heres my `metadata.rb`:

```
name 'awesome_customers_rhel'
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'all_rights'
description 'Installs/Configures awesome_customers_rhel'
long_description 'Installs/Configures awesome_customers_rhel'
version '0.1.0'

depends 'selinux', '~> 0.9.0'
depends 'firewall', '~> 2.4.0'
depends 'httpd'
```

Any attempt I make to use `depends 'httpd'` causes this error.

I'm working through a [tutorial](https://learn.chef.io/manage-a-web-app/rhel/configure-apache/) on using the chef [httpd cookbook from Chef Supermarket](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/httpd) to configure a kitchen test instance.  However I'm stuck at [step 6](https://learn.chef.io/manage-a-web-app/rhel/configure-apache/#step6). Kitchen wont converge due to some issue with compat_resource, the only difference between the guide and my cookbook is that I'm using httpd verion 0.4.0

```
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.11.1)
-----> Converging <default-centos-72>...
       Preparing files for transfer
       Preparing dna.json
       Resolving cookbook dependencies with Berkshelf 4.3.5...
       Removing non-cookbook files before transfer
       Preparing validation.pem
       Preparing client.rb
-----> Chef Omnibus installation detected (install only if missing)
       Transferring files to <default-centos-72>
       Starting Chef Client, version 12.14.60
       resolving cookbooks for run list: ["awesome_customers_rhel::default"]
       Synchronizing Cookbooks:
         - awesome_customers_rhel (0.1.0)
         - selinux (0.9.0)
         - firewall (2.4.0)
         - httpd (0.4.0)
         - chef-sugar (3.4.0)
         - compat_resource (12.14.3)
       Installing Cookbook Gems:
       Compiling Cookbooks...

       ================================================================================
       Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/httpd/libraries/helpers.rb
       ================================================================================

       LoadError
       ---------
       cannot load such file -- chef_compat/resource

       Cookbook Trace:
       ---------------
         /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/httpd/libraries/helpers.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

       Relevant File Content:
       ----------------------
       /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/httpd/libraries/helpers.rb:

         1>> require 'chef_compat/resource'
         2:  
         3:  module HttpdCookbook
         4:    module Helpers
         5:      def default_apache_version
         6:        return '2.2' if node['platform_family'] == 'debian' && node['platform_version'].to_i == 7
         7:        return '2.2' if node['platform_family'] == 'debian' && node['platform_version'] == '12.04'
         8:        return '2.2' if node['platform_family'] == 'debian' && node['platform_version'].to_i == 6
         9:        return '2.2' if node['platform_family'] == 'debian' && node['platform_version'].to_i == 7
        10:        return '2.2' if node['platform_family'] == 'omnios'

       Platform:
       ---------
       x86_64-linux


       Running handlers:
       [2016-09-18T19:03:29+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
       Running handlers complete
       [2016-09-18T19:03:29+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
       Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds
       [2016-09-18T19:03:29+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
       [2016-09-18T19:03:29+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
       [2016-09-18T19:03:29+00:00] ERROR: cannot load such file -- chef_compat/resource
       [2016-09-18T19:03:29+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: 1 actions failed.
>>>>>>     Converge failed on instance <default-centos-72>.  Please see .kitchen/logs/default-centos-72.log for more details
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

Heres my `.kitchen.yml`

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
  network:
    - ["private_network", {ip: "192.168.33.33"}]

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

platforms:
  - name: centos-7.2

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[awesome_customers_rhel::default]
    attributes:
```

Comment: Looks like issue with `- compat_resource (12.14.3)`. Try with old `- compat_resource (12.10.6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already filed as an issue here https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/httpd/issues/95

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment

Comment: It's as much of an answer as the user will get here. I'm not debugging it twice in two places.